# An error TypeError: Object(...)()[Symbol.iterator]().next().value is undefined when try run a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

> An error TypeError: Object(...)()Symbol.iterator.next().value is
> undefined when try run a react from the after creating a statePovider

```
import React, {createContext,useReducer,useContext} from 'react';

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState,children}) =>(

    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer,initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>    

    ); 

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

App
C:/Users/Jokanola/Documents/Web Project/bettersociety/src/App.js:14

> 11 |
> 12 |
> 13 | function App() {
> error  14 | const [ { user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
> 15 |
> 16 |   return(
> 17 |

the folder containing App shown here

```
import React from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import Header from './Components/Header';
    import Sidebar from './Components/Sidebar';
    import Chat from './Components/Chat';
    import SignIn from './Components/SignIn.js';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
    import {useStateValue} from './Components/stateProvider';
    
        function App() {
        const [ { user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
        
          return(
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    {
                        !user? (
                        <SignIn />
                    ):(
                   <div>
                    <Header />
                       <div className="App_body">
                            <Sidebar /> 
                                <Switch>
                                    <Route path="/room/:roomId">
                                        <Chat />
                                    </Route>            
                                </Switch>
                         </div> 
                    </div>
                    )
                  }
                </Router>
            </div>
        
        
            )
        }
        
        export default App;
```

this is index.js were I rapped app conponent with StateProvider

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {StateProvider} from './Components/stateProvider';
import reducer, { initialState } from './Components/reducer';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <StateProvider reducer={reducer} initalState={initialState}>
        <App /> 
      </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: you didn't use your `StateProvider `

Comment: I used it in index.js,

Comment: so post it plz.

Comment: I have posted it

Answer (score 2):

```
const [ user] = useStateValue();
```

in App.js

and

```
const [user,dispatch]=useStateValue();
```

in signin.js

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

The spelling of initial state when you are wrapping App with state provider is wrong. Correct it to `initialState`